# How to bind Instanceproperty to viewmodel, view is not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Problem:**

My Viewmodel creates a instance of a controller `mycontroller` and the property `Busy` shall be passed to the View and updated in the View based on the controller state, but my View doesn't get updated. The other property `Busy2` is updated based on the current state. Bindablebase implements the I

**Question:**

Why the property `Busy` in the ViewModel is not updated? The mycontroller.Busy property is updating, but not the view.

**Framework & Tools:**

PRISM 6.3.0

Fody.Propertychanged

**View:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Busy}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Busy2}"></TextBlock>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class Controller
    {
        public bool Busy { get; private set; }

        public async void GetValue()
        {
            Busy = true;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Busy = false;
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private readonly Controller _mycontroller;
        public DelegateCommand<string> RunCommand { get; private set; }

        // This property is not updated in the view
        public bool Busy
        {
            get { return _mycontroller.Busy; }
        }

        // Works as aspected
        public bool Busy2 { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            _mycontroller = new Controller();
            RunCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Run, Canrun).ObservesProperty((() => _mycontroller.Busy));
        }

        private bool Canrun(string arg)
        {
            return _mycontroller.Busy != true;
        }

        private void Run(string obj)
        {

            Busy2 = true;
            _mycontroller.GetValue();


        }
    }
```

**Update:**

I added the Bindablebase from Prism, because is implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, but the view is still not updated. 
I refactored the code and I set a breakpoint to  set `{ SetProperty(ref _busy, value); }` and the breakpoint is never reached.

I removed the Propertychanged.Fody nuget package too.

**ViewModel:**

```
   public class Controller : BindableBase
    {
        private bool _busy;
        public bool Busy
        {
            get { return _busy; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _busy, value); }
        }

        public Controller()
        {

        }

        public void DoWork1()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                _busy = !_busy;
                Debug.WriteLine(_busy.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void DoWork2()
        {
            _busy = !_busy;

        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private Controller mycontroller;
        private string _title = "Prism Unity Application";

        public DelegateCommand RunCommand { get; private set; }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
        }

        public bool Busy
        {
            get { return mycontroller.Busy; }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            RunCommand = new DelegateCommand(Execute);
            mycontroller = new Controller();

        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            mycontroller.DoWork1();
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="PropertytestPrism.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding RunCommand}" Content="Run"></Button>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Busy}"></TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Update 2**

1. Failure: Missing INotifypropertychanged for the class Controller

The View is still not updated and the reason for this is my Delegatecommandmethod, which executes mycontroller.DoWork1();

**Question:**

Why the View is not updated? If I execute the method inside the DelegateCommandmethod?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` by your `Controller` class. Property is changed inside `Controller` class and this changing should be notified:

```
public class Controller : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _busy;

    public bool Busy 
    {
        get
        {
            return  _busy;
        } 
        private set
        {
            SetField(ref _busy, value, "Busy"); }
        } 
    }

    public async void GetValue()
    {
        Busy = true;
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Busy = false;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
           handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your bindings work like this.

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Busy,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>.`

By default bindings are one time and so they wont be updated even on the property changed notification.